# How can I display only specific data in my gridview considering other database tables field in my database

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I have a database table tbl_Employee which stores employee_code as primary and another database table tbl_Salary which has a fields employee_code and ammount. Now, my question is, how can I display on my datagriview those employees that has their salary set?

Comment: Um, you query the database tables such that `salary is not null`.  I think your question is a bit light on details, and doesn't show any attempt by you to get this to work.  I suggest that you edit the question and add some additional detail, including your current attempt.  As it stands, your question is at risk of being closed due to a lack of detail / effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you must explain your question a bit more. For example, you have pointed out only one column name and two table names. What we want to retrieve from tbl_salary? And you must write your code which causes problem or on this situation, you must show examples for your tables. That is the reason that you have a downvote already.

Now, for your question, use SQL command like this;

```
SELECT *.tbl_Employee, *.tbl_Salary 
FROM tbl_Employee INNER JOIN tbl_Salary
ON tbl_Employee.employee_code = tbl_Salary.employee_code
```

Comment: Thank you so much, sir not only for the answer but also for the tip in living here. :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you might be looking for. Since I dont have the REP to comment I assume You might be looking for a query to get the data where salary of the employees has been set and thus you can get the data like this

USING JOIN

```
SELECT te.* from tbl_Employee te
JOIN tbl_Salary ts ON
te.employee_code = ts.employee_code
```

Using WHERE

```
SELECT te.* from tbl_Employee te, tbl_Salary ts
WHERE te.employee_code = ts.employee_code
```

Comment: thank you soo much sir. can't comment more longer :) I commend you for this.